# How to find a UDP flow made of a single packet?

Tags: udp, wireshark

I am reading a network measurement-related paper, and the authors proposed a method to tell a scanning packet from the other type of packets when the payload of the transport layer was removed. One of the conditions is that the UDP flow is made of a single packet.
So I am wondering are the packets with the same stream index in one UDP flow? If so, how can I count the number of UDP flow made of a single packet efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

*... are the packets with the same stream index in one UDP flow?*
Yes.  A stream index is just a number assigned to a 5-tuple consisting of the source IP address, source port, destination IP address, destination port and the IP Protocol, in this case UDP.  If there's only 1 packet per flow then the stream index will only identify that single packet as part of that particular flow.

*If so, how can I count the number of UDP flow made of a single packet efficiently?*
With [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), you can load a capture file and then choose *"Statistics -> Conversations -> UDP"* and sort by Packets.  If there are any flows consisting of a single packet, then it should be easy to see them using this method.  If you want to know how many UDP flows consist of only a single packet though, then you'll have to count them manually.

An easier method for simply counting the number of UDP flows that consist of only a single packet is to use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), which is part of the Wireshark suite and is the command-line equivalent of Wireshark, along with a few other command-line tools such as [`sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html), [`uniq`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) and [`grep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1p.html).  For example:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y udp -T fields -e udp.stream | sort -n | uniq -c | grep "^[ ]*1 "
```